# How to add a link (or any html) to a getter response in Vuex?

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

I'm building a blockchain explorer using Vue and Vuex and I stumbled upon a problem I can't solve thus far.

Essentially I have a getter that returns a full transaction info based on operation name. For instance, if the operation is `po_transfer`, I want to give user details on what type of asset, quantity, sender and receiver of this particular operation `(@mat sent 10 BTC to @ned)`.

Since I collect data from different applications and games of one particular blockchain, I have dozens of these operations (transfer, open, cancel, sell, purchase, issue, build, explore, upgrade and so forth). Thus, I created a getter that returns all of that in a human readable form, instead of `po_transfer`.

It works perfectly with text but I need to add a link in my response as well.
In our previous example `(@mat sent 10 BTC to @ned)` [@mat](https://example.com/@mat) and [@ned](https://example.com/@mat) should be links that lead to correspondent websites that I set up for them.

So my question is - how to I add link inside of the Vuex getter response?

I already tried to use plain javascript with `document.body.appendChild(myLink)` but it only shows an href text (`http://somewebsite.com/@mat`), instead of actually giving me an embedded link (`@mat`) that leads to this href.

Here's what I have now:

```
 dappInfo: (state, getters) => (op, id) => {
   if (op === 'transfer') {
     return getters.dappJsonByTrxId(id).from + ' sent ' + 
            getters.dappJsonByTrxId(id).amount + 
          ` to @${getters.dappJsonByTrxId(id).to}` 
   }
 }

   dappJsonByTrxId: (state) => (id) => {
     return state.transactions.find(t => t.transaction_id === id).operations[0][1] || ''
   }
```

I need this `getters.dappJsonByTrxId(id).from` to return [@mat](https://example.com/@mat).

`` <a href=`example.com/${getters.dappJsonByTrxId(id).from}> @${getters.dappJsonByTrxId(id).from}<a/> ``
doesn't work as well. It returns me `<a>..</a>` in a text form.

I assume you're not supposed to return html in getters but I really need to solve this one because everything else is working. Would really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

P.S. You can check the demo of explorer [right here](https://steem-apps-explorer.firebaseapp.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can output string value containing all your html tags `<a href=".... />` composed in a getter and then output it as html using `v-html` directive, f.e. `<div v-html="yourJsString"/>`.

When composing string with html, ecmaScript templates aka string interpolation may come in handy.